# Custom push notification

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, android-push-notification, custom-notification

how to send custom push notification to 1.5 million users with there name in body using firebase or SNS push notification?

For example: we have username: Santosh, Fcm: adgbbdghjjjbc

Then user will get notification with body as following

```
Hey Santosh, hope you are doing good....
```

I have tried with firebase which is taking long time to send notification.

Implementation:

```
message = messaging.Message(
    data=update_body,
    token=device_token,
    )

response = messaging.send(message)
```

Here we create an `update_body` dictionary, which includes user's information.

Using the `update_body` dictionary, we construct a `message` object using Firebase's messaging API. This object contains the notification data and the `token` representing the user's device.

Finally, we call the `messaging.send()` function to send the notification message using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).